# Can I override age restrictions for specific apps?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, parental-controls, screen-time

My young teenager has an iPhone with parental controls turned on. One setting will only allow apps rated 12+.

I prefer 12+ as a default setting, but there are a couple of 17+ apps that I find acceptable which won’t run.

**Is there a way to override age restrictions for specific apps? If so, how?**

[image: screenshot of Allowed Store Content via ScreentSetting]